# Kinect depth data ONLY

Tags: kinect, raspbian, openkinect

Is there a way in linux (raspbian) to capture only the depth data stream from a kinect? I'm trying to reduce the amount of processing needed to capture Kinect information so I want to ship the data stream to another computer to assemble the data.

Note:

- I have freenect installed but anything that requires opengl will not run on rasbian.
- I have installed [this example](http://sphinx.mythic-beasts.com/~markt/RPi-openCV-Kinect.html) which captures the data stream with a b+w visual depth display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[librekinect](https://github.com/xxorde/librekinect) is a Linux kernel module that lets you use the depth image like a standard webcam.  It's known to work with the Raspberry Pi.

But if you want to use [libfreenect](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect) for full video/depth/motor support, you'll need a more powerful board like the [ODROID XU-3 Lite](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G141351880955).  By the way, libfreenect only requires opengl for some examples.  The rest of the project compiles and runs fine without.

Comment: It looks like the odroid and the rpi are roughly the same size. Do you know for sure?

Comment: The original RPI had awful USB bandwidth and was not suitable for simultaneous video and depth streaming.  The RPI 2 might be better in that regard.  The ODROID I linked is [known to work](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/issues/84#issuecomment-74173615).